# Cannot insert lines into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic database that consists of three tables :

- Product(idP,name,price,quantity,stock_Minimal,stock_maximal)
- Order(ref,date)
- Order_Line(idP,ref,quatity)

the product table contains a catalogue of all the product available, the order table contains a list of all the orders references and their respective dates,and finally the order_line table contains informations about whats been ordered in every command

here is the code that I use to insert an order into the order table and its lines to Order_Line table:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
    $ref             = $_POST['ref'];
    $date            = $_POST['date'];
    $choosed_product = $_POST['choosed_product'];
    $quantity        = $_POST['quantity'];
    $cn              = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($cn, "vente_db");
    $res = mysqli_query($cn, "select * from commande where ref=" . $ref);
    $cn->close();
    if ($res != null) {
        $cn->query("insert into Order_Line values (" . $choosed_product . ",$ref,$quantity)");
    } else {
        $co = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysqli_select_db($co, "vente_db");
        mysqli_query($co, "insert into Commande 
values('$ref',''$date'')");
        mysqli_query($co, "insert into Order_Line values 
(" . $choosed_product . ",$ref,$quantity)");

    }
}
?>
```

But when I check the databse I don't find the inserted lines,can you please help me figure out the problem in my code

[edit]:I know that my code is vulnerable to sql injections, but this is just for a school project and we're not required to secure the database against hackers.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the phpmyadmin software itself. I'm going to assume you meant mysql, and re-tag

Comment: You are mixing two implementations...

Comment: What is `$choosed_product`? If it's not an integer, your query might fail.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also **Never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.

Comment: Anyway you're mixing procedural and OO implementations of mysqli, and also not checking for mysql errors. And you don't need to keep repeatedly re-connecting to the same database within one PHP script. I suggest taking an introductory tutorial.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't anderstand what do you mean by that

Comment: @AmineHammou Do you understand PHP? The value inside the variable I mentioned should be an integer and not a string. If it's going to be a string, you need to cover it inside `''` single quotes.

Comment: @AmineHammou Please have a look at my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues with this code. Your code is very much vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks! I have commented everything inside the code:

1. Put connection string in the first line for making it available to use.
2. Add the DB selector to the connection.
3. Give an alternate message if connection fails.
4. Make sure you sanitize the data.
5. Optional: Make sure you backtick the column names and add single quotes for values.
6. This is not needed here. `$cn->close();`
7. Make sure you use the same implementation. Either OOP or Procedural.
8. You don't need another connection. `$co = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ""); mysqli_select_db($co, "vente_db");` Use the previous connection.
9. You have an error in the SQL Syntax with double single quotes.
10. Add single quotes for the values.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
    // Put connection string in the first line for making it available to use.
    // Add the DB selector to the connection.
    // Give an alternate message if connection fails.
    $cn              = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vente_db") or die("Cannot Connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    // Make sure you sanitize the data.
    $ref             = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, $_POST['ref']);
    $date            = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, $_POST['date']);
    $choosed_product = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, $_POST['choosed_product']);
    $quantity        = mysqli_real_escape_string($cn, $_POST['quantity']);
    // Optional: Make sure you backtick the column names and add single quotes for values.
    $res = mysqli_query($cn, "select * from `commande` where `ref`='" . $ref . "'");
    // This is not needed here.
    // $cn->close();
    if ($res != null) {
      // Make sure you use the same implementation. Either OOP or Procedural.
      mysqli_query($cn, "insert into `Order_Line` values ('" . $choosed_product . "', '$ref', '$quantity')");
    } else {
      // You don't need another connection.
      // $co = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
      // mysqli_select_db($co, "vente_db");
      // Use the previous connection.
      // You have an error in the SQL Syntax with double single quotes.
      mysqli_query($cn, "insert into `Commande` values('$ref', '$date')");
      // Add single quotes for the values.
      mysqli_query($cn, "insert into `Order_Line` values ('" . $choosed_product . "', '$ref', '$quantity')");
    }
  }
?>
```

This should probably work. If not, at least it would tell you why it failed.

Comment: Surely we should include a check for SQL errors after each mysqli_query? And it's assuming that all the variables are strings, which there's no evidence for either way in the question.

Comment: @ADyson Exactly... It's kinda optional, but a good practice... Nothing's gonna be wrong if we add some good practice right? `:)`

Comment: well my point was that the checking for errors after each query is not there in the answer

Comment: Guys I'm sorry if I haven't provided enough about the variables but I know enough to know how to handle integers and varchar..and I haven't provided what errors are being displayed is because no error is being displayed..it just executes and then when I check the databse I find nothing